# Swift 2.0 do block not executing in dataTaskWithURL

Tags: ios, swift2

I grabbed a version of this code from this site (thanks to Sergey A. Novitsky). However, the 'do' block is never executed so the "json" variable is always nil. What's going on? I'm using Xcode 7.0 Beta.

```
func getJson(url:NSURL) -> NSDictionary! {

        var json:NSDictionary!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {
            (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in

            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary
            } catch let caught as NSError {
                print(caught)
            } catch {
                // Something else happened.
                let error: NSError = NSError(domain: "<Your domain>", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
                print(error)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        return json
    }
```

Comment: You can not perform asynchronous task if you want to return the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers you need a completion block like this

```
func getJson(url:NSURL, completion: (json:NSDictionary?, error:NSError?)->()) {

  let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
  let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {
    (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in

    do {
      let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary
      completion(json: json, error:nil)
    } catch let caught as NSError {
      completion(json: nil, error:caught)
    } catch {
      // Something else happened.
      let error: NSError = NSError(domain: "<Your domain>", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
      completion(json: nil, error:error)
    }
  }

  task.resume()
 }
```

call the function with

```
getJson(NSURL(string:"http://myserver.com")!) { (json, error) -> () in
  if error != nil {
    print(error!)
  } else {
    print(json!)
    // do something with the json dictionary
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That code runs, but I see odd results. It takes about a minute for the call the return (on Xcode 6, it was super fast) and even with the error trapping, I'm still getting: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1):

That's not how asynchronous functions work. `json` is nil when it's returned because it won't actually be set until the asynchronous completion block for `dataTaskWithURL` is called. To get the value out of `getJson`, pass in a completion block of your own and call it inside the task's, passing back the parsed JSON to your calling site.